# Postgres copy command to import .csv using quote option creates more double quotes in destination table

Tags: postgresql, csv, copy, double-quotes

I want to import a .csv file ('|' delimited) into a postgres table. Below is the sample data of csv file. Data in this csv file has a double quote (")
45926052|3|70092111944|ketamine" Syringe|25180|5902629|1.00000|||4|Pham|2018-08-30|9999-12-31
I use the below code to import this data in the postgres table.

copy  public.destination_tbl
from 'D:\Target\sample_data.csv'
DELIMITER  '|'
QUOTE E'$'
csv header

Below image you can see the data in destination table after import. Here you can see a double quote in the first column and extra two double quotes near the actual double quote.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dorW6.png)

I want the data imported in the table to be same as it is present in the source csv file.

Comment: Sounds like you manipulated the file in Excel, and it transformed it into its own idea of a csv file, with only one column.  Examine the file with a text editor, and I think you will find the extra quote marks are literally present in it.

Comment: yes jjanes, what you say is correct. Thanks!

Comment: @jjanes Actually I am trying to copy data from csv to a postgres table, The csv data has double quotes in the data, as double quote is a default quoting character the copying fails when it encounters a double quote in data. As a solution I used the quote parameter in the copy command and made the default quote character as some other special character. But my data has almost all the special character. How can I copy the data from csv to pg table along with the special characters